# VBScript Syntax: MS Word Merge Field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a macro that places a conditional merge field with nested IF statements. Most users just copy the merge fields from one document and paste them into their final draft. However, there are numerous conditional merge fields to choose from. Using a command button that inputs the merge field instead of copying and pasting will illuminate user error and speed up this process. Any help is much appreciated.

- A macro that places a multi-nested conditional IF statement into a
  document.
- Below is the code I created. Where it reads, “truetext:=”True,” is where I need to insert another merge field.

Thank you for reading and for your interest!

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim mName As String
Dim dField As Word.MailMergeDataField

Set doc = ActiveDocument

doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="""Client_FirstName"""
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

doc.MailMerge.Fields.AddIf Range:=Selection.Range, _
mergefield:="""Client_MiddleName""", Comparison:=wdMergeIfIsNotBlank, _
truetext:="True", _
falsetext:="False"
Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    
doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
    Name:="""Client_LastName"""

doc.MailMerge.Fields.AddIf Range:=Selection.Range, _
mergefield:="""Client_NameSuffix""", Comparison:=wdMergeIfIsNotBlank, _
truetext:="""Client_NameSuffix""", _
falsetext:=""
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in code instead of using a properly-configured mailmerge main document?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the question. I code documents with merge fields, and there are numerous pre-coded merge fields where the user copies and pastes them into the document. My aim is to streamline this by placing/organizing these in a user form, where the user clicks a command button to insert a specific merge field. My hope is this will increase efficiency and decrease user errors. In short, I’d like to click a button that places a conditional statement based on sex (his or her), for example. I hope this makes sense. Thanks again for your interest.

Comment: At the moment your request is rather vague. It may help if you take time to review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65877962/edit) the question to focus on the specific help you need.

Comment: Save them as AutoText or another building block in your template. You can put a custom building block gallery in the template or could do call them through your userform. Coding nested fields is a nightmare. You can do it if you have to but I won't help with it.

Comment: Timothy, thanks for pointing the vagueness out. Instead of searching through numerous pages to find a specific pre-written IF statement that’s on a separate document, I want to load them into their own respective macros, click the command button, and voilà it’s there. I already have the forms completed with buttons to choose from, but I hit a wall when coding the “if true” in the merge field. I simply don’t know how to insert a “mergefield.field.add…” as “true” instead of “truetext…” 
Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: Charles, thank you for sharing your thoughts! I use building blocks, but there are too many to remember, which is why I was hoping to replace a separate document containing all the pre-written IF statements. Specifically, the document containing pre-written IF statements functions as a middleman. If I can load them in VB, click a button for a specific merge field, and then appear on the document. I have it working for everything except conditional statements.

Comment: A properly configured mailmerge main document can employ field coding and/or the \b and \f switches to generate conditional output. There is no need for on-the-fly vba for this. See the many examples at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. Otherwise, if the documents have substantial differences, you should consider the use of INCLUDETEXT fields and/or different mailmerge main documents for different purposes. As it is, you have the tail trying to wag the dog.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts and the link, which is very rich in information and I bookmarked it. The issue is: document A contains numerous variations of merge fields that serve as a template for the user to copy and paste into a never ending number of documents. Instead of constantly searching through document A for a unique code field IF statement, store the merge field code in a macro that’s actuated by a command button, thus cutting out the need for document A. Please let me know if this makes sense. Thanks again for your interest, thoughts, and the informative web link.